# 'hello/Hello.h' file not found - Trying to build/run iOS gomobile Hello app

Tags: xcode

I am building the [gomobile Hello](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile#building-and-deploying-to-ios) example app, but am running into the following problem: When trying to build and run the app after opening it in Xcode (7.1), I get the error 'hello/Hello.h' file not found'
From what I can tell, Hello.h is in fact in the hello folder of the native directory.

[image: Xcode Error Message]

Comment: Post your problem code here. Don't use screenshots to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13441) on Github, it seems like this is due to a recent change in the way Xcode 7 updates paths for the headers.

The proposed solution is to check `Copy items if needed` when importing the framework:

[image]

I can confirm that this fixes the issue. But note that you would then need to re-import the framework every time you make changes and build the go code.

Comment: @ZAK Glad to have been of help!